# Redirect to Opportunity on save of task on the lead

Tags: apex, lightning, tasks, lead-conversion

The requirement is whenever a new task is created on the lead. The lead should get converted into Account/Contact/Opportunity and I am able to convert it using standard LeadConvert class But after the lead is converted I want to navigate the user to the newly converted opportunity record detail page.

[image]

Is it possible?

Currently, it is displaying like 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in the specific situation that your user is adding a Task via a Quick Action on the Lead Lightning Page, but only with quite a bit of additional development work. Adding Tasks through other channels, like the API, Salesforce Classic, etc., may or may not have a solution but would certainly have a different one if any. There is no general method whereby your Apex backend code can intervene in a UI session.

What you'd have to do is establish a "listener" component on the Lightning Record Page for your Lead. That listener, using the `<lightning:empApi>` component, would wait for a specific Platform Event to be posted with a payload that included the Lead Id for the page it's sitting on. Then, your Apex code would post that Platform Event when it's done with the conversion process, and include the Id of the new Opportunity.

Your listener component could then use the `<lightning:navigation>` API to request navigation to the record page for the new Opportunity, whose Id is in the payload of the Platform Event.

Comment: Do you have an article or help document on the above solution.

Comment: No. I've never even implemented it, to be honest. I believe it would work but I can't make a promise. What you're asking is not something that is generally supported.